# Is it possibile to find out the length of original data from a AES-CBC cphertext?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes

I'm using VC++/OPENSSL and AES-256-CBC, and I noticed that since AES is automatic padding by OPENSSL and when I try to decryption , the data I got is with the padding bytes. not just original data.

is there anyway to get length of the original  data at decryption  so I can cut the padding bytes?

here is my code

```
void Cryptology::OpenSSLAESDecodeByMapleArray(MapleByteArray& source, MapleByteArray& ba,MapleByteArray &res,bool nosalt)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX de;

    unsigned int salt[] = { 56756, 352466 };

    int i, nrounds = 7;
    unsigned char key[32] = { 0 }, iv[32] = { 0 };
    if (nosalt)
    {
        i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), NULL, ba.data_ptr(), ba.GetLength(), nrounds, key, iv);
    }
    else
    {
        i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), (unsigned char *)salt, ba.data_ptr(), ba.GetLength(), nrounds, key, iv);
    }

    if (i != 32) {
        exit(0);
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&de);
    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&de, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);


    int p_len = source.GetLength(), f_len = 0;
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc(p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    ZeroMemory(plaintext, p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&de, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    EVP_DecryptUpdate(&de, plaintext, &p_len, (unsigned char *)source.data_ptr(), source.GetLength());
    EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&de, plaintext + p_len, &f_len);

    int len = p_len + f_len;


    //qDebug() << QString::number(len);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&de);


    res.fromByte((BYTE*)plaintext, p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    ZeroMemory(plaintext, p_len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
    free(plaintext);
    ZeroMemory(key, 32);
    ZeroMemory(iv, 32);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The padding usually follows a convention (just can't remember it at the moment) for example `ddddddppppb`. Where `d` are data bytes, `p` are padding bytes and `b` is the number of padding bytes.

Comment: I see Richard. but is there anyway do make OPENSSL to do the padding and unpadding automatically?  I am too lazy to code :P

Comment: It is preferable you encode the data size with the data and don't rely on the padding and some automatic data size deduction. If the encoded data is truncated, you want to be able to detect that. This is why you encode the data size in front of the data and check that the data has not been truncated. It is then trivial to also drop the padding or any garbage that may have been added after the encrypted message. Your code will be more robust.

Comment: Quick reading of the docs says that OpenSSL uses  PKCS#7 padding, so find the API in OpenSSL to add/remove the padding.

Comment: @chmike There are standard for padding the you must use if your want your encryption scheme to be standards based. See  PKCS#7 padding for example.

Comment: @Richard Critten The padding is taken care by OpenSSL. But one should use a defensive strategy and provide means to make sure the decrypted data is Ok. The minimum is thus to encode the message length along with the data. A checksum or a MAC in addition to that would be preferable. The program should react "gracefully" if the data has been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If padding is enabled - then `EVP_DecryptFinal(..)` will verify the padding but not return it in the result. Those the decrypted data would be slightly shorter than the encrypted data.

The actual length of decrypted data is returned in the `outl` variable with each call to `EVP_CipherUpdate(..)` and `EVP_CipherFinal_ex(..)`

```
    int EVP_CipherUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
                         int *outl, unsigned char *in, int inl);
    int EVP_CipherFinal_ex(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *outm,
                          int *outl);
```

In your code, the value of `len` is properbly the length of your decrypted data.